# Как сделать запрос из РНР к базе данных MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: Сама таблица]

Имеется таблица `bot` в phpMyAdmin. Как правильно составить на php запрос, который извлечет данные столба `money` определенного `user_id`?

Например получить значение `money` для `user_id = $id` (значение столбца в переменной). После этого, значение `money` нужно будет поместить в переменную `$money`.

Можно для примера решение данной ситуации, чтобы потом уже разобраться на готовом примере с остальными запросами?

Comment: А в чём у вас сложности?

Comment: Не понимаю, как правильно вытащить значение столбца X строки, в которой значение столба Y = 123

Comment: инфы в интернете больше, чем число в вашем поле `money`

Comment: используйте условие `WHERE`

Comment: @Андрей Лёвушкин, пожалуйста, укажите в вашем вопросе (отредактируйте его), как вы пытаетесь подключиться к БД (mysqli, PDO, как-то еще), как формируете и посылаете запрос на выборку данных, и какая проблема при этом у вас возникает. Без этой информации ответить на ваш вопрос весьма затруднительно.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с базой данных в РНР служит класс PDO.

#### Соединение с БД

Для соединения с MySQL надо написать такой код (взят [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#example)),

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

вписать свои собственные значения для параметров подключения и поместить в файл `db.php`.

После этого в своем скрипте написать `include 'db.php';` и после этого в нем будет доступна переменная `$pdo`, которая будет использоваться для всех запросов к базе данных.

#### Выполнение запроса

Выполнение запроса SELECT включает в себя 3 стадии:

- подготовка запроса, при этом на место всех переменных ставятся знаки вопроса. При этом создается переменная $stmt.
- выполнение запроса, при котором все участвующие в запросе переменные отправляются отдельно, в виде массива, в метод `$stmt->execute()`.
- получение запрошенных данных. Данные можно получить тремя разными способами

  - одну строку в виде массива или объекта, `$stmt->fetch()`
  - массив строк, если запрос может вернуть больше одной строки, `$stmt->fetchAll()`. После этого полученный массив можно будет вывести через `foreach()`.
  - единственное значение - если мы запрашиваем единственную колонку единственной строки, `$stmt->fetchColumn()`
  - в очень редких случаях получение может быть выполнено четвертым способом - выборка по одной строке в цикле, но мы его здесь рассматривать не будем.

Это схема для выполнения любых запросов, в которых участвуют переменные. В данном случае код будет таким:

```
include 'db.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT money FROM bot WHERE user_id=?'); // подготовка
$stmt->execute([$id]); // выполнение
$money = $stmt->fetchColumn(); // получение
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `bot` WHERE `user_id` = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $id).'"';
```

Переменная $mysqli - это ваше подключение к БД, если вы используете подключение к БД, как в примере:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Но вам, как начинающему программисту, желательно сразу использовать подключение к БД только через PDO - это более безопасный вариант. В этом случае синтаксис запроса в $query придется немного подредактировать.

Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ваш вопрос так, как я написал в комментарии, и тогда у сообщества Stackoverflow будет больше шансов помочь вам.

Comment: так зачем приводить пример mysqli?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Mysqli заражена чумой, не работает или не нравится вам лично?