# Как обновить запись из таблицы mysql при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных mines есть таблица info
Там есть колонка balance со значением 0
Как обновить запись из таблицы info при нажатии на кнопку? (образно, при нажатии на кнопку значение с колонкой balance изменяется на другое число)

Comment: обработать нажатие кнопки и послать к таблице запрос UPDATE

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922253/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%A0%D0%9D%D0%A0-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-mysql). Вопрос в целом аналогичен, разница лишь в том, что вам нужен `UPDATE`, а не `SELECT`